# A linear manifold in a Hilbert space is dense if and only if it has trivial orthogonal complement

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Conway, in *A Course in Functional Analysis*, leaves the following corollary (2.11) to the reader.

> If $\mathcal S$ is a linear manifold in $\mathcal H$, then $\mathcal
>  S$ is dense in $\mathcal H$ iff $\mathcal S^\perp=(0)$.

The term linear manifold denotes a linear subspace that is not necessarily closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per Potato's request:

It is well know that $\mathcal{S}^{\perp\perp}=\overline{\mathcal{S}}$. So, if $
\mathcal{S}^\perp=0$, then $\overline{S}=\mathcal{S}^{\perp\perp}=\mathcal{H}$.

Conversely, if $\mathcal{S}$ is dense, and if $x\in\mathcal{S}^\perp$, then $f(v):=\langle v,x\rangle$ is a continuous function vanishing on the dense set $\mathcal{S}$, and thus must be identically zero. Thus, $x\in\mathcal{H}^\perp=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $S$ is dense, and suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\mathcal S^\perp$ contains a nonzero element $v$. Because $\mathcal S$ is dense, we may choose a sequence $\{s_n\}$ in $S$ such that $s_n\rightarrow v$. We have

$$\|v\|^2 = \langle v,v\rangle = \langle v-s_n, v\rangle \le \|v-s_n\| \|v\|.$$

The right side tends to zero as $n$ tends to infinity, so $v=0$, a contradiction.

For the converse, suppose $\mathcal S^\perp =0$. We know from Corollary 2.10 that $(S^\perp)^\perp=0^\perp=\mathcal H$ is the closed linear span of $\mathcal S$.

Comment: If $x\in\mathcal{S}^\perp$ then doesn't the continuous function $f(v)=\langle v,x\rangle$ vanish on a dense set?

Comment: @AlexYoucis I think so. You should add that as another answer.

Comment: @Potato Hi, I do not get why $<v, v> = <v - s_n, v>$. Could you please explain it further? I am starting in functional analysis.

Comment: @noether We have $\langle v-s_n, v\rangle = \langle v,v\rangle - \langle s_n, v\rangle=  \langle v,v\rangle $ because $\langle s_n, v\rangle=0$ by the orthogonality assumption ($v\in S^\perp$).

Comment: @Potato Thank you very much, I have figured it out but now I see the reasoning behind.